# illegal_argument_exception when creating an index alias - Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I am trying to create an alias with a filter of an index pattern metrics-* . I was able to do it yesterday and the day before without any problems but I can't do it again today, even if I re-run the same queries as yesterday. I have no problem creating an alias of logs-* . But when I try to create a metrics-* alias, I get an HTTP 400 code with this as response:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "expressions [metrics-system.filesystem-default, metrics-system.cpu-default, metrics-endpoint.policy-default, metrics-endpoint.metrics-default, metrics-windows.perfmon-default, metrics-azure.compute_vm-default, metrics-system.process.summary-default, metrics-elastic_agent.endpoint_security-default, metrics-endpoint.metadata-default, metrics-endpoint.metadata_current_default, metrics-azure.storage_account-default, metrics-system.memory-default, metrics-system.uptime-default, metrics-elastic_agent.elastic_agent-default, metrics-windows.service-default, metrics-elastic_agent.metricbeat-default, metrics-system.fsstat-default, metrics-system.process-default, metrics-elastic_agent.filebeat-default, metrics-system.network-default, metrics-system.diskio-default, metrics-system.load-default, metrics-system.socket_summary-default] that match with both data streams and regular indices are disallowed"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "expressions [metrics-system.filesystem-default, metrics-system.cpu-default, metrics-endpoint.policy-default, metrics-endpoint.metrics-default, metrics-windows.perfmon-default, metrics-azure.compute_vm-default, metrics-system.process.summary-default, metrics-elastic_agent.endpoint_security-default, metrics-endpoint.metadata-default, metrics-endpoint.metadata_current_default, metrics-azure.storage_account-default, metrics-system.memory-default, metrics-system.uptime-default, metrics-elastic_agent.elastic_agent-default, metrics-windows.service-default, metrics-elastic_agent.metricbeat-default, metrics-system.fsstat-default, metrics-system.process-default, metrics-elastic_agent.filebeat-default, metrics-system.network-default, metrics-system.diskio-default, metrics-system.load-default, metrics-system.socket_summary-default] that match with both data streams and regular indices are disallowed"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Here is the request body :

```
PUT metrics-*/_alias/perso-metrics

{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "agent.name" : "minecraft-server"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some of your indices which are starting with name `metrics` is not data-streams and are regular indices, in Alias request you can't have both of them, if you try to create aliases separately for `data-stream` and `regular indices` it will work.